# How to fix: setState does not work in gastby?

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I'm using gatsby for server side rendering.

Here's my code:

```
class BookSearch extends Component {

    state = {
        search: '',
        books: '',
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        this.loadData()
    }

    loadData () {
        axios.get('/books/list')
            .then(response => {
                this.setState({books: response.data.books});
                console.dir(response.data.books);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                this.setState({error: true});
            });
    }
```

Unfortunately, this.setState does not work in gatsby. componentDidMount is not being called when I load the page. What should I do?

Comment: Hi Pota, check my solution and let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is of binding `this` to `loadData` method.

You can bind this in 2 ways.

1. Bind `this` in the constructor,

```
constructor(props){
   super(props)
   this.state = {
        search: '',
        books: '',
    }
    this.loadData = this.loadData.bind(this)  //Bind this here
}
```

2. Or you can simply use arrow function,

```
loadData = () => { //Arrow function auto binds `this`
   axios.get('/books/list')
   .then(response => {
        this.setState({
           books: response.data.books
        }); 
        console.dir(response.data.books);
   })
   .catch(error => {
      this.setState({error: true});
   });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should have got an error? It's because you have not initialized `error` state. You must initialize state before you can use them:

```
state = {
   search: '',
   books: '',
   error: false
};
```

I hope this may fix the issue. Otherwise, I couldn't see any issue in your code.

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned you're using SSR?
Try using `componentWillMount` in this case, since `componentDidMount` is not called in SSR.

In case you're using react version > 16.3:

> When supporting server rendering, it’s currently necessary to provide the data synchronously – componentWillMount was often used for this purpose but the constructor can be used as a replacement. The upcoming suspense APIs will make async data fetching cleanly possible for both client and server rendering.

Reference: https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/27/update-on-async-rendering.html#fetching-external-data

In your case, I think it would make more sense to use the getInitialProps static method. (https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/fetching-data-for-pages/fetching-batman-shows)

If you're not very familiar with SSR, Next.js has great tutorials:
https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/getting-started

This may help you out!